# Unable to boot my Mac

Tags: macos, mac, troubleshooting

When I turn on my MacBook, the white screen appears but it does not finish booting and show my desktop. I've tried restarting several times now.

Comment: any one give me the solution

Comment: You do realize that it's not even daytime on half the planet? Give people some time.

Comment: @Daniel Beck -  sorry Danie take your own time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resetting the PRAM and NVRAM as described [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379). Since it's a Macbook, also [reset your PMU](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1431).

Can you boot into [Single User](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1492)? What happens when you try?

Can you boot from the System DVD? Can you enter [Hardware Test](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509)? What happens if you do/try?

Comment: i'm using single user i can't boot into to desktop directly when i turn on MacBook it will take 4-6 attempt to enter

Comment: @sribharanidharan: OK. If you can boot into [Safe Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1455), you probably have a bad driver. If you cannot boot into Safe Mode, you should reinstall Mac OS X. All your data is preserved if you don't erase the disk.

Comment: @Daniel-Thanks for you valuable comment